# Replacing a 3 speed ceiling fan pull switch with another 3 speed fan switch

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

The old switch was a "Defond E 72989" the one I bought was a Harbor Breeze 3 speed fan switch 0033905, now the fan will not come on at all. HELP
It has a 3 wire capacitor.

Comment: The terminals if the new switch may not be in the same order as the old switch. Or you mayy have miswired it without that excuse.

Comment: Please post a picture of the wiring